# How to print to different brands of USB POS printers with the same code?

Tags: windows, printing, driver

My application should support different brands of POS printers, all these printers are connected via USB to the PC. Currently, my app uses drivers provided by different venders to print.

Is there a way to print to all these printers with the same code?

I guess it depends on whether there is a general USB printer protocol that every printer supports?

PS:
Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. If I want the users of my application to plug in a POS printer to PC, and without the hassle of installing any drivers, start printing in my application, which API should I use to write the code?

1. Print Spooler API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx
2. WinUSB API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196(v=vs.85).aspx
3. libusb: https://github.com/libusb/libusb

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're asking, but as a general design guidance: if you want to use the same code, you need a common interface to code to - either provided to you or written by you. If you're creating the interface, you'll need to make the implementations as well, and the implementations would be specific to each type you want to support. It sounds like you want to wrap each vendors driver in your interface.

Comment: @Chris Is there such a common interface? Windows has a spooler API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx, but does every POS printer support this API? Or do I need to install a vendor-specific driver to use spooler API?

Comment: You will need drivers anyway. USB doesn't tell printers what they should do. Some eat PCL, some PS, some XPS, some something else. If they provide regular printer drivers, that's the way to go. But not knowing which printers you are going to use it's impossible to say.